# На каком языке написать программу?

Tags: любой-язык

Хочу написать для себя программку, которая бы имела свое окно в котором программа открывала бы сайты и делала на сайте какие то действия.

Но вот встал вопрос, на каком языке это лучше всего делать?
Сейчас мой выбор пал на C# но вот не знаю, правильно ли это. Может для такой задачи можно использовать какой то другой язык, который предназначен для этого?

Comment: На том языке, который вы знаете лучше всего и, самое главное, знаете как такую программу написать и представляете себе все ее функциональные части и как их правильно на этом языке написать.

Comment: C# - хороший выбор для этого. Необходимая малость - надо хорошо владеть С# под такие требования.

Comment: Если сайт официально предоставляет API - берите любой язык, который лучше всего знаете. Если собираетесь писать бота, который будет жать на кнопочки на странице - возьмите AutoIt.или AutoHotKey.

Comment: python+selenium вполне себе решение для того, чтобы открыть сайт, и выполнять на нем какие-нибудь действия. + python весьма дружелюбен к новичкам...

Comment: Или обычный JS и пишите расширение для хрома

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей возможно будет лучше питон, так как проще для начинаний.

во 1 Питон имеет простой ситаксис, и как я понял тот кто задавал вопрос либо не учился вовсе либо очень мало. Во 2 в питоне есть библиотека xPath и фреймворк scrapy и если нужно будет логиниться то библиотека Requests все это довольно эффективно используеться и подойдет для целей. Также сделав свою цель можно будет расширить функционал.

Comment: А надо не для начинаний, а для конкретной задачи. Да и вообще какой-то неподробный ответ.

Comment: во 1 Питон имеет простой ситаксис, и как я понял тот кто задавал вопрос либо не учился вовсе либо очень мало. Во 2 в питоне есть библиотека xPath и фреймворк scrapy и если нужно будет логиниться то библиотека Requests все это довольно эффективно используеться и подойдет для целей. Также сделав свою цель можно будет расширить функционал.